# Extracting specific data from huge JSON

Tags: json, flutter, http

I'm trying to get nutritional data from a web API in Flutter, but the JSON I get back is way bigger than what I actually need. I want to first try to extract only the name of the item, but I just can't seem to get it with Flutter.

Here is the JSON I get, you can try putting the URL in postman if you want, because it is way too big to put here:

https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v2/product/069000147344.json

I tried to get the data like a TypeScript HTTP request (ex : `food.name = response.data[1].values.name`), but it won't let me do the `.value.name` because it's actually in the JSON and not integrated with a method.

Comment: Use `response.json()` then access the Python nested dict/list returned

Comment: I don't know Flutter, but if you don't want the whole JSON then don't use an HTTP library that downloads the whole JSON. You really need an HTTP library and a JSON parser that will let you stream the JSON and parse it while it's still downloading. Then you can stop the download once you have the data you do need.

Comment: See [JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/serialization/json)